# Hide code errors in php but still execute the rest of the page

Tags: php, exception

I am hoping that someone can help me: I have this scripts that if a file does not exists on my server, it goes to a remote server to check for the file. If the file exists it copies it to my local server, and does not check it again. So the Imagick part only works when the image does not exists on my local server.

The problem that I have is that if the file does not exists on the remote server - then the application throughs a error - Here is the code of my script:

```
        <?php if (file_exists($filename))
    {
echo '<img src="'.$imageurl1.'" width="'.$g_sites_img1.'" alt="'.$imageurlmeta.'" class="image1" align="left" />';
    }
else { $imageurlfolder = dirname($filename); 
@mkdir($imageurlfolder, 0755, true);
@copy($imgremoteurl, $filename);
$thumb = new Imagick($filename); 
$thumb->scaleImage($g_sites_img1, 0);
$thumb->writeImage($filename);
$thumb->destroy(); }?>
```

Here is the error code:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'ImagickException' with message
> 'Unable to read the file:
> /home/game1/public_html/images/small///.jpg'
> in
> /home/game1/public_html/includes/standard__1.php:15
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/game1/public_html/includes/standard__1.php(15):
> Imagick->__construct('/home/game1/pub...')
> #1 /home/game1/public_html/includes/news.php(127):
> require('/home/game1/pub...') #2
> /home/game1/public_html/index1.php(126):
> include('/home/game1/pub...') #3
> {main} thrown in
> /home/game1/public_html/includes/standard__1.php
> on line 15
```

How can I avoid this error but still make the page load normally?

I have tried error_reporting(0); <--- This stops the page from completely loading once the error has occured.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

I have found the solution with all the answers posted! thanks a million

```
<?php if(file_exists($filename))
```

{ echo ''; }
else { try {$imageurlfolder = dirname($filename);
@mkdir($imageurlfolder, 0755, true); @copy($imgremoteurl, $filename);
$thumb = new Imagick($filename);
$thumb->scaleImage($g_sites_img1, 0); $thumb->writeImage($filename);
$thumb->destroy();}
     catch (ImagickException $e) {
             echo "Exception caught!\n";
     }
     }
    ?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you should catch the exception, don't try ignoring the errors. After all, you are getting fatal error which prevents further logic from being executed.

```
try
{
    // your logic
}
catch ( ImagickException $e )
{
    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: Thanks David - Found it with your help!

Comment: Missing an 'x' between the E and c

Comment: Nice catch @celwell, much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default local image if the file does not exists on the remote server.

Comment: Nice alternative idea - actually answers another problem that I haven't got to yet!

Answer (score 1):

use a catch block

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the manual - I am new to php so it is the first time I had to deal with the "try and catch functions" very helpful - To read it on the php site

Answer (score 1):

This is an [exception](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), not an error.

You need to catch it and then handle it:

```
try {
  $thumb = new Imagick($filename); 
  // do your thing with it
  $thumb->destroy();
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
  // something went wrong, handle the problem
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are looking for is called a try-catch statement.
[Here is what PHP docs have to say about it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting(0); works for errors, not exceptions:

```
try {
    // your code
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // code that runs in case an error appears
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (copy($imgremoteurl, $filename)) {
    // image functions
} else {
    // error copying image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it in a [`try`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block and you can handle the error and choose to ignore it or whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score -3):

Fatal errors are just that -- FATAL. The script has died, and it's not going to go any farther because the rest of it depends on that data being present.

Add some error-handling in the event that the file doesn't exist on the remote server, and you should be ok.

Comment: Holy downvotes, Batman! Care to explain why you don't agree with my answer?

Comment: It's a misleading answer.Errors and exceptions are two different things in this context.

Comment: @Claudiu: I suppose I used the wrong term, then.. What I meant was: If you handle the Error ("file doesn't exist on remote server"), then you avoid the Exception ("Imagick unable to read non-existant file").